# How to change the font in Visual Basic editor (UI & Code) in Office 365 for Mac

Tags: vba, office365

I used the vb editor about a month ago, and all was fine.  When I opened it up today, all of the fonts both in the UI and the code are in Times New Roman.  (I'm using Office 365 for Mac.)

I've tried going to Excel > Preferences > Editor Format > Font and can choose a different font, but nothing changes when I do so.  (On the contrary, if I change one of the other options, like foreground color, the editor updates immediately.)

I haven't been able to find any help on how to change the font if the Editor Format Options don't work.

Help!

[image: screenshot of vba editor]

Comment: Seems buggy. Does the behavior still persist if you reopen Excel?

Comment: Yeah, I've restarted Excel and restarted my computer.  I've also tried getting to the editor from different files in case it had something to do with the workbook I was in.

Comment: FWIW I can't repro (version 16.28 (19081202) - I'm on Office Insider). Looking at your screen shot, I don't see any font selected, nor a Sample. When I change the font (to TNR, for example) only the print in the *code window* changes, not in the Project or Properties windows. You appear to be dealing with some kind of system setting. Are you seeing this anywhere else on your Mac?

Comment: When I select a font, it'll show that font in the font dropdown and the sample window.  But when I click 'OK' and then re-open Options, the font and sample windows are blank again.

I had the same thought on system settings.  I don't see TNR anywhere else on my system, not even in Excel.  Do you know where I could see a font system setting?